# [Twilio][Whatsapp] My message stuck in Queued

Tags: facebook, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-php

Before, the WhatsApp sending service via Twilio has been running for almost 2 months, and currently all the messages I send have stopped being Queued.

[image: postman]
[image: log]
[image: sender]

I have tried creating a new number, a new sender, sending via the API provided or the Vendor installed.

Comment: Are you sending these messages within a 24hrs window? And if not, can you confirm the message body matches a pre-approved template string?
Also, please show the postman config of the message you are sending.